# Terraform azure virtual network module

Tags: azure, terraform

I have written the below code for creating a virtual network in terraform azure:
I have files in the root folder for main.tf,variables.tf and terraform.tfvars. I have got two modules for resource group and virtual network.

In the root folder  I have the below code:
main.tf

```js
#Resource Group Creation
module "resource_group" {
  source     = "./modules/resource_group"
  rgname_var = var.resource_group
  loc_var    = var.location

}
#Virtual Network Creation
module "vnet" {
  source                = "./modules/vnet"
  loc                   = module.resource_group.loc_o
  rgname                = module.resource_group.rgname_o
```

terraform.tfvars:

```js
vnet_name             = "VirtualNetwork"
vnet_address_space    = [<3 subnet ips>]
```

variables.tf:

```js
variable "vnet_name" {
  default = ""
}

variable "vnet_address_space" {
  default = ""

}
```

In the vnet module, I have the below code:

```js
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet_name
  count               = length(var.vnet_address_space)
  address_space       = var.vnet_address_space[count.index]
  location            = var.loc
  resource_group_name = var.rgname

} 
#Subnet Creation
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet-1" {
  name= var.subnet_name1
  resource_group_name  = var.rgname
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefix       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[0].vnet_address_sace

  
}
#Subnet Creation
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet-2" {
  name= var.subnet_name2
  resource_group_name  = var.rgname
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefix       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[1].vnet_address_sace

  
}
#Subnet Creation
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet-3" {
  name= var.subnet_name3
  resource_group_name  = var.rgname
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefix       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[2].vnet_address_sace

  
}
```

I am getting the below error for three subnets:

*19:   address_prefix       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[0].vnet_address_sace
This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
"vnet_address_sace".*

I have tried giving one ip for virtual network address space at the first place,because it was working for single subnets. then the system was expecting list instead of string.
Any idea how to set the values for virtual network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [azurerm_virtual_network](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network) cocs, the correct argument is `address_space`, not `vnet_address_sace`. So in the code, it should be:

```
azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[0].address_space
```

not

```
azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[0].vnet_address_sace
```

Comment: I am using address space. vnet_address_space is a variable I have created to pass the value from tfvars.

Comment: @Asterix I mean here `azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[0].vnet_address_sace`? There is no such thing as `vnet_address_sace`.

Comment: @Asterix It should be `azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[0].address_space`.

Comment: Yup,you are correct, that was a mistake, but it gives another issue now:19:   address_prefix       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[0].address_space
    |----------------
    | azurerm_virtual_network.vnet is empty tuple

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

Comment: @Asterix It should be `azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[0].name`, just like with `address_space`. The index, 0, 1, ..., must be adjusted to correctly reflect your setup.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. If we are creating a virtual network via azure portal, we wil be giving the name for virtual network . I believe thats the value "azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name"  holds. and I have added the variable subnet_name1,subnet_name2 etc for the respective subnet names. Isnt it how it works?

Comment: @Asterix You are creating your vnets using `resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" ` with `count`. Because you have `count` you have to use [0], [1], and so on to refer to the vnets created. I'm not sure how it relates to console. Sorry.

Comment: okay , what I understood is I am actually creating 3 Vnets , not subnets for one Vnet. this wasnt what I wanted to acheive.:) . The reason why I gave address space as list is , it wasnt allowing me to assign a single ip.

Comment: Yes Marcin, its indeed helpful .I will create a new question then . Thank you :)